# Organizando arquivos Javascript na solução

Tags: javascript

Pensando no conceito de HTML 5 e padrões web modernos temos que em uma página web, o arquivo HTML deve proporcionar a estrutura, o arquivo de estilo CSS deve proporcionar a formatação e o Javascript deve proporcionar o comportamento da página.

Olhando por esse aspecto, como deveríamos dividir nosso código javascript? Um arquivo para cada página, um "arquivão" com todos os eventos e métodos de todas as páginas?

Deveríamos ter para cada página web, um arquivo `.html` e um `.js` separados?

Qual a recomendação de vocês?

[ATUALIZANDO PERGUNTA 05/03/2014]

Eu entendo que não e uma pergunta que terá um certo ou errado mas meu objetivo eh coletar o maior numero de diferentes opiniões e tomar minhas conclusões baseado nos comentários e respostas dos colegas.

Para responder uns vão considerar a reusabilidade do código, outros vão considerar performance, outros a manutenção, etc.

Minha pergunta não eh em consideração ao uso de frameworks JS existentes e sim minhas próprias rotinas.

Por exemplo, digamos que eu tenha uma pagina que tem uma combobox e eu quero que ao selecionar um valor algo aconteça na pagina, seja manipular outros objetos via DOM ou executar alguma operação remota com Ajax. Em algum lugar da minha pagina eu terei um javascript para executar isso. Minha pergunta então se aplica: para esse tipo de codigo javascript, eu crio um arquivo por pagina, deixo o JS no arquivo html (cshtml, php, o que for) ou coloco todas essas pequenas rotinas em um único js e linko a todas as paginas, ou qualquer outra variação disso.

Acho uma discussão valida que pode agregar valor a muitos.

O que vocês recomendam?

Comment: Isso depende muito. Dentre outras coisas, da estrutura da aplicação. Você pode dividir o código em dezenas de arquivos js, e compilar um arquivo único, minificado, para ser entregue ao browser. Em geral, quanto menos arquivos você entrega ao browser, mais rápida fica a app.

Comment: Ficou vago, a resposta vai depender da opinião individual.

Comment: Conforme o comentário do @bfavaretto a "melhor prática" pode variar de um grande arquivo minificado até uma estrutura modular complexa com vários arquivos (a la [AMD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asynchronous_module_definition)). Você encontrará pessoas advogando um, outro ou nenhum dos dois conforme as características do problema, *background* de quem está respondendo e opiniões pessoais.

Comment: Na minha opinião, o que está explícito na pergunta é bem objetivo ("como dividir o código"). Somente o que está implícito é que é subjetivo ("como dividir do ponto de vista da performance" vs "como dividir do ponto de vista da organização lógica" vs outros pontos de vista). Ou seja, não é o caso de fechar, basta editá-la colocando um pouco mais de contexto (i.e. focando naquilo que pode ser respondido objetivamente). P.S. vou remover a meta-tag "melhores-praticas", outras tags relevantes podem ser adicionadas depois conforme o contexto.

Comment: Cada framework que você utilizar vai ter suas melhores práticas, sendo que AngularJS, Polymer-project, Backbone, ExtJS, MeteorJS, e varios outros, cada um vai ser diferente. Então está no mínimo vago e baseado em opinião. A resposta vai ser vaga tb, algo do tipo MVC, HMVC ou no estilo de Web Components, todas vão falar pra juntar arquivos e minifica-los. Mas não respondem por completo a pergunta do rapaz. Se ele especificar o ambiente qual ele quer organizar pode ser possível ajuda-lo.

Answer (score 2):

Os dois principais fatores nessa decisão são o tempo de download e o uso da cache. Ambos são conflitantes, sendo necessário fazer um *trade-off*.

Não enviar o código que uma página não vai usar reduz o tamanho do arquivo e consequentemente o tempo de download, fazendo com que a página renderize mais rapidamente. Entretanto, quando a próxima página for carregada seu código não estará na cache (pois ele é diferente do da primeira página) e ele terá de ser baixado novamente. Ou seja, maximiza-se a performance individual, mas compromete-se a coletiva.

Já usar um "arquivão" com todo o código do site possui a característica oposta: a primeira vez que um visitante acessar o site ele o encontrará lento, pois há uma grande quantidade de dados a serem descarregados. Mas se ele continuar até o final (i.e. não desistir e fechar a aba do *browser* antes do site carregar) vai encontrar um site mais rápido que o usual - já que todas as páginas usam o mesmo código, que agora está na cache do navegador.

À primeira vista pode parecer então que usar vários arquivos é melhor - pois tudo o que é comum às várias páginas irá pra cache, só o que é novo que será baixado a cada nova página. Mas na realidade isso não é bem assim. Quando se faz uma requisição ao servidor, há um *overhead* de se estabelecer a conexão, enviar o pedido e receber a resposta. Se vários arquivos forem combinados em um, esse overhead é **amortizado** entre eles, já que haverá apenas um pedido e uma resposta (ainda que longa). Com vários, haveria vários pedidos e várias respostas (um *round-trip* para cada arquivo).

### O que fazer então?

Em primeiro lugar, garanta que o visitante não vai desistir do seu site sem nem olhar. Faça o que for preciso para que sua *home page* seja tão rápida quanto possível (e de preferência tão portável quanto possível - funcionando inclusive com JavaScript desabilitado). Em outras palavras, "compile" um JS específico para ela. Para as demais páginas, compensa condensar tudo num arquivo só, já que a lentidão inicial se pagará a longo prazo. Ou, se seu site for bem "particionado" (ex.: área do cliente, área dos funcionários), criar arquivões específicos para cada conjunto de casos de uso.

Se seu código usa bibliotecas populares (como jQuery), pode ser interessante baixá-las de um CDN em vez do seu próprio site. Não tenho informação sobre quais deles têm mais tráfego (e portanto, já têm o código em cache no maior número possível de computadores), mas seria algo a se considerar caso se use um CDN gratuito.

### E quanto ao lado do desenvolvedor?

Como apontado nos comentários, do ponto de vista do resultado final (i.e. aquilo que será enviado ao cliente) não importa muito a forma que você organiza seus fontes - já que os mesmos deverão no mínimo serem minificados antes de usar (a compressão padrão dos web servers ajuda, mas não substitui todos os benefícios da minificação). Como esse tópico já é mais subjetivo - melhor forma de organizar, melhor ferramenta para "compilar", etc - vou me abster de expressar uma opinião.